# UIImagePNG representation from AVFoundation returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a capture output delegate method:

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
        let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        let cameraImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)

        filter?.setValue(cameraImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter?.setValue(0.0, forKey: kCIInputSaturationKey)

        let filteredImage = UIImage(ciImage: filter!.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.cameraView.image = filteredImage
        }

    }
```

where I add filter to my live preview image. But if i try to create NSData from the image by this method: UIImagePNGRepresentation() it's return nil and I have don't idea why. If I use CameraViewController all works perfect so I think that the problem is in AVFoundation. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `UIImage(ciImage:)` does not convert a CIImage to a normal UIImage. You need to render into a normal UIImage backed by a CGImage.

Comment: but my filteredImage.cgImage return nil.. :/

Comment: Correct, that's exactly my point. You asked why you cannot get NSData from this UIImage and I told you why! As I said in my answer, you have to _render_ your CIImage. You have not done that. Your UIImage has no `cgImage` because you did this wrong. No `cgImage`, no Data.

Comment: working ;) thanks :)