# Fastest way to render CIImage to JPEG?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, core-image, ciimage

I have a `CIFilter` pipeline.

It currently outputs `UIImage` using:

```
private func renderImage(ciImage: CIImage) -> UIImage?
{
    let cgImage = Filter.context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)

    return cgImage.map(UIImage.init)
}
```

This `UIImage` is later converted to JPEG and stored.

There's now a demand to filter images in bulk and skip the `UIImage` format.  This needs to be done as fast as possible.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42591183/1971013) are a few ways to do this.

Which way is the fastest?

Comment: Just a word of caution: conversion from CIImage to actual image is never fast, as all the filters / transformations are applied on conversion (although they are optimized). If speed is really important, consider using Accelerate framework (i.e.: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/building_a_basic_image-processing_workflow)

Comment: @KirilS. Being new to Accelerate, I guess that would mean I'd have to implement the CIFilters that come with iOS myself and rewrite myMetal filters?

Comment: Oh, yea, with Metal filters it's not worth it. I was thinking more about built-in filters. The conversion from CIImage to JPEG may still be slow-ish, especially for RAW images. But you will see. Good luck!

Comment: @KirilS. Why isn't it worth it to use Accelerate with Metal filters? Aren't all builtin CIFilters in Metal?

Comment: I meant _if_ image's destination is a bitmap, _and_ you are using some built-in filters, you are wasting (potentially a long) time on converting from CIImage to CGImage / JPEG. Instead you could use Accelerate directly on bitmap (Apple provides some good examples on how to do the same built-in filters with Accelerate). However with your custom filters, translating them to Accelerate, debugging those filters, and testing whether the lost ability to run on GPU is compensated by speed of conversion to bitmap - that's not realistic.

Comment: Can give you an example. We had a chain of 4 CI filters: resample, greyscale, rotate, sharpen - simple chain. But convert back to JPEG took a long time - about 7 sec per (raw) image. Most of the time was the conversion (i.e. disabling all the filters didn't improve anything). So we tried the Accelerate and with it got processing time down to about 3 sec per image. So yea, filter application itself was obviously slower, but since it needed no conversion, the total time was much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the `CIContext` as well:

```
let colorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!
// if you need the JPEG data
let data = Filter.context.jpegRepresentation(of: ciImage, colorSpace: colorSpace)
// or if you want to write to file directly
try Filter.context.writeJPEGRepresentation(of: ciImage, to: url, colorSpace: colorSpace)
```

Comment: Where is the type `Filter` coming from? Is this `CIFilter`?

Comment: I was picking this up from OP's code. I guess `Filter` is some type in their codebase. `Filter.context` is an instance of `CIContext`.